# serverfireteam/panel how to format datetime?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

im using serverfireteam/panel from https://github.com/serverfireteam/panel.

I have build this controller with a datetime value:

```
class TransportController extends CrudController{

public function all($entity){
    parent::all($entity); 
    $this->filter = \DataFilter::source(new \App\Transport);
    $this->filter->add('datum', 'Datum', 'datetime');
    $this->filter->submit('search');
    $this->filter->reset('reset');
    $this->filter->build();

    $this->grid = \DataGrid::source($this->filter);
    $this->grid->add('nummer', 'Nummer');
    $this->grid->add('datum', 'datum');
    $this->grid->add('spediteur_id',"Spediteur Id");
    $this->grid->add('fahrer_id',"Fahrer Id");
    $this->grid->add('fahrzeug_id',"Fahrzeug Id");

    $this->grid->add('transportkosten',"Transportkosten");
    $this->addStylesToGrid();

    return $this->returnView();
}

...

}
```

I like to format the datetime  value (like $this->grid->add('datum', 'datum')->format('d.m.Y');) but I couldn't find the function to format it.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you will use Carbon to format dates (and more)

Add this at the top of your controller:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

And then you can use it so:

```
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '11/06/1990');
```

With carbon you can do several things as for example:

```
Carbon::now()->year
```

Read the documentation it will be very useful:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. The problem is that with /serverfireteam/panel the entitys are renderd direcly in a view. They use https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel but when I tried blade($this->grid->add('{{ date_format(einlagerungsdatum,"d.m.Y") }}', 'Einlagerungsdatum');) syntax as descriped under Data grid it just renders out  {{ date_format(einlagerungsdatum,"d.m.Y") }} at the view and not the result.

Comment: If you are getting the date from a timestamp from db than you can do: "  {{date('d-m-Y', strtotime(   your-returned-date    ))}} "